# using explode in php to separate a string of multiple images

Tags: php, html, image

i am selecting rows from a database and using the below to separate each image (all in one column)

```
$images = explode(',',$result['images']);
```

then to display one image i am using this HTML / PHP Code:

```
<img src="/img/project-gallery/'.strtr($images[0],'[]','""').'"
```

but its displaying like below

```
<img src="/img/project-gallery/" 5_b.jpg""="">
```

how can i make it display like a image is suppose to

in my database, the images are all in one column like:

`[image1.jpg],[image2.jpg],[image3.jpg]` etc...

Comment: why not just do `substr($images, 1, -1)`

Comment: I suspect there are spaces after the commas, you need to remove them. Also, you shouldn't replace the brackets with quotes, you should just remove them.

Comment: ... I mean substring in a loop.

Comment: ive used /img/project-gallery/'.substr($images, 1, -1).' but it says Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: any ideas why im getting the error

Comment: cause $images is an array. You'd have to do something like `foreach($images AS $image){ echo substr($image, 1, -1); }` obviously tailor this to fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

use it this way worked for me

```
$images = explode(',',$result['images']);
```

Then in the img src file

```
<img src="xxxx/xxx/<?php echo strtr($images[0],'[]',''); ?>">
```

It will select only one image file as long as ur images are arranged in your database in  one column like

[image1.jpg],[image2.jpg],[image3.jpg] etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = explode(',',$result['images'] );

foreach($temp as $image){
    $images[]="/img/project-gallery/".trim( str_replace( array('[',']') ,"" ,$image ) );
}
//now your array of images cotaines to full source to each image

foreach($images as $image){
  echo "<img src='{$image}' />";
}
```